# Play a single note with DirectMusic

Tags: midi, xaudio2, directmusic

I'm using DirectMusic for MIDI playback in an application I'm developing. Does anyone know if it's possible to use DirectMusic to play individual notes? Currently, I'm converting an in-memory data structure that represents entire 'songs' into a MIDI buffer and playing it back through DirectMusic. I'd like to be able to play individual notes without having to generate a MIDI buffer for it, loading it and playing it. Is this type of thing even possible with DirectMusic?

This is my first excursion into the world of DirectMusic so hopefully I'm not too uninformed of it's capabilities...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *believe* that stuffing your note messages into a DirectMusicBuffer8 and then playing that is indeed the simplest way to do it.

I assume you're aware that DirectMusic is deprecated, not recommended for new development etc. etc.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I'll see if I can dig more info up on that on MSDN.

I am aware DirectMusic is deprecated, however, my understanding is that XAudio2 has very poor support for MIDI. Unless I'm mistaken on that - I would switch to XAudio2 in an instant if it supports MIDI, as I'm only in the early stages of integrating DirectMusic into my application.